# Anaconda: How to completely delete Python 3.4?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I installed both Python 2.7 and 3.4 on my Mac (using the graphical installers from http://continuum.io/downloads). I only need to use 2.7. How can I completely delete 3.4? Thanks.

Comment: That depends a good deal on how you installed it in the first place. Provide as much information as possible. At the moment your question is rather vague and therefore will probably down-votes.

Comment: http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/faq.html#uninstall-anaconda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [Anaconda FAQ](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/faq.html#uninstall-anaconda):

> How do I uninstall Anaconda? Version 1.3.1 and later
>
> Anaconda can be uninstalled by removing the root directory (~/anaconda
>   by default; use the conda info command to confirm the location of the
>   root directory). Version 1.4 and newer
>
> OSX and Unix uninstalls remain the same as in previous versions.
>
> On Windows, click the Start button, and navigate to the Control Panel
>   and select Uninstall a program, then find Anaconda in the list of
>   programs

---

So you'll have to look in `$HOME/anaconda` and delete the appropriate Python installation from there.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the anaconda directory. You can see what directory Python 3 is installed into by starting Python 3 and running

```
import sys
print(sys.prefix)
```